# How to setup a program in python?

Tags: python, installation, package, directory, program-entry-point

I wrote a python program which I call with arguments from console. As the functionality grew, so did the amount of code that is now all nested in one single file.

I know that there are python modules and packages which I could create in order to outsource the functions I wrote. But is this really the python way of doing things?

How would the folder structure look like? Something like

```
prog
  __init__.py
  module1.py
  module2.py
prog.py
```

where `prog` (a directory or python package) and `prog.py` share the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good solution, thought your modules should be stored in a package *not called like your main module*. This would be prone to conflict between module and package name.

This could be `resources`, `lib` or anything, but please, not `prog`, as you already have a module named `prog.py`; otherwise, how would you know the result of `import prog`?

Note: from what I can see in my Python 2.6 install, with the structure and names you propose, you get no error message, but cannot access to `prog.py` content.

Comment: I can confirm that trouble arises when I call my package `prog`. But since I have in the root directory also other programs like `prog` what name should I give the `prog`-package? Just `lib` or `resources` would not make the package distinguishable from other packages other programs might use...?

Comment: What about `prog_lib` or `lib_prog`? Then, you could have other folders like `prog_test` or `test_prog`, 'prog_resources', etc, depending on the way you want them to appear in your main folder.

Answer (score 1):

That's a fairly normal development cycle - any set of functions/methods that have a common purpose or relate to a common set of data are candidates for splitting off into separate modules.   The functions must be loosely coupled with the rest of the code (communicate through function call arguments and return values, not shared variables), and the act of splitting them off into separate modules makes it easy to identify shared variables that should be converted into function interfaces.  Modular programming is definitely Pythonic!

You don't need to set up a separate folder for your modules, just give the .py files meaningful names that relate to their function.  I wouldn't call a file prog_lib.py, I'd call it prog_graphics.py if it did plots, spincalcs.py if it did calculations on rotating objects :-), etc.

Comment: Since I have multiple programs in my root folder, I'd rather create packages instead of modules which are located in the same folder as my `prog.py`. Like that I know, that each file in my root directory is a program.